# No puede leer la propiedad 'on' undefined cuando reemplaca con la mia database

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb

Estoy tratando de reemplazar la base de datos de [un repositorio que cloné](https://github.com/sylwolveryn/nodejs-quizzes) con mi propia base de datos:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var achievementSeeder = require('../app/achievementsSeeder');

// connect to db ===============================================================

(function () {
    "use strict";
    let connection = mongoose.connection,
        connected = false;
    // mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_MLAB_URI || 'mongodb://sandboxUser:huiokj@ds011880.mlab.com:11880/quizzessandbox'); // former one
    mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_MLAB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://sandboxUser:huiokj@cluster0-vk6pd.gcp.mongodb.net/test'); // mine
    connection.once('open', function() {
        console.log("database connection:");
        mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection('achievements', function(err, result) {});
        achievementSeeder.seedAchievement();
        if (process.env.MONGOOSE_MLAB_URI) {
            console.log("sucesfully connected to database");
        } else {
            console.log("sucesfully connected to sandbox database");
        }
    });
    mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
        connected=true;
        console.log('open connection to mongo server.');
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function (ref) {
        connected=true;
        console.log('connected to mongo server.');
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function (ref) {
        connected=false;
        console.log('disconnected from mongo server.');
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('close', function (ref) {
        connected=false;
        console.log('close connection to mongo server');
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
        connected=false;
        console.log('error connection to mongo server!');
        console.log(err);
    });

    mongoose.connection.db.on('reconnect', function (ref) {
        connected=true;
        console.log('reconnect to mongo server.');
    });
})();
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar `npm start` tengo el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Quizzes\nodejs-quizzes\config\mongoModule.js:48
    mongoose.connection.db.on('reconnect', function (ref) {
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Quizzes\nodejs-quizzes\config\mongoModule.js:48:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Quizzes\nodejs-quizzes\config\mongoModule.js:52:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Quizzes\nodejs-quizzes\index.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! quizzes@0.0.1 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the quizzes@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T14_16_27_283Z-debug.log
```

Así que no sé si mi error está relacionado con el `Failed at the quizzes@0.0.1 start script.` (no sé qué significa) o conmigo y mi base de datos.

Comment: es `mongoose.connection.on` sin el `db`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta conectarte a mongo de la siguiente manera

```
        mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://sandboxUser:huiokj@cluster0-vk6pd.gcp.mongodb.net/test')
    .then(db =>{
       //Aqui puedes hacer un console.log de correcto
       console.log('Conexion con mongodb exitosa')
    })
    .catch( err => {
      //Aqui va el error al conectar puedes colocar
      console.log('error al conectar con mongodb, ocurrio el siguiente error ' + err)
    })
```